# Unique solution in infinitely many homogenous linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Assume there is a system of countably infinite many homogenous linear equations $E_1,E_2,E_3,\dots$ with variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$. Each equation has only finitely many variables.

I am wondering is it possible that the whole system has the unique trivial solution, and in each equation, at least one of $x_2,x_3,\dots$ shows up?

**Edit:** both the comment and an answer give an example.
What if we add one more condition: we require there is a surjective map $f$ from $\{x_2,x_3,\dots\}$ to $\{E_1,E_2,\dots\}$ such that if $f(x_i)=E_j$, then $x_i$ shows up in $E_j$.

For example, the system of $2x_1=0,x_2=0,\dots$ has unique solution but none of $x_2,x_3,\dots,$ shows up in $2x_1=0$. The system $x_i+x_{i+1}=0$ for $i=1,2,\dots$, the required variables shows up in each equation but the system does not have unique solution.

Comment: Maybe something like $x_1+x_2=0, x_1-x_2=0, x_2+x_3 = 0, x_2-x_3=0, \ldots$ or $x_1=0, x_1+x_2=0, x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ (but there is one $E_i$ where only of $x_1,\ldots$ has nonzero coefficient).

Comment: Thanks! I edited the problem a bit to require there are not "so many" equations.

Comment: OP, you can't keep changing the problem like this. -1

Comment: Nothing changed after the one revision within 5 min of the post. I just started a bounty and I don't think it bothers/offenses you. (The original question was trivial and I forgot to address the necessary condition, which my examples are to illustrate.)

Comment: And it makes no sense to downvote my question, unless you can solve it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, even with the additional condition. The intuition is there is always room for infinity, as illustrated by Hilbert's hotels.

---

Here is an example.

$$\begin{align}
x_1+(x_2 + x_3) &= 0\\
x_2+x_3\ &= 0\\
x_3+(x_4+x_5) &= 0\\
x_4+x_5\ &= 0\\
x_5+(x_6+x_7) &= 0\\
x_6+x_7\ &=0\\
\vdots
\end{align}$$

Note that $x_{i}$ appears in $E_{i-1}$ for all $i\ge2$.

---

We can even require there is a surjective map $f$ from $\{x_{k_1},x_{k_2},x_{k_3},\dots\}$ to $\{E_1,E_2,\dots\}$ such that if $f(x_{k_i})=E_j$, then $x_{k_i}$ shows up in $E_j$. Here $\{x_{k_1},x_{k_2},x_{k_3},\dots\}$ is any given subset of all variable $x_i$'s.

Here is an example.
$$\begin{align}
x_1+(x_{k_1} + x_{k_2}) &= 0\\
x_{k_1}+x_{k_2}\ &= 0\\
x_2+(x_{k_3} + x_{k_4}) &= 0\\
x_{k_3}+x_{k_4}\ &= 0\\
x_3+(x_{k_5} + x_{k_6}) &= 0\\
x_{k_5}+x_{k_6}\ &= 0\\
\vdots
\end{align}$$

---

Adapting the example above slightly, we can show the following strong generalization.

Given a map $\sigma$ from $\Bbb N$ to the powerset of $\Bbb N$ such that $\{i:j\in\sigma(i)\}$ is finite for all $j\in\Bbb N$, there is a system of linear homogeneous equations $E_1,E_2,\cdots,$ on variables $x_1, x_2, \cdots$ with the unique trivial solution $0=x_1=x_2=\cdots$ such that if $j\in\sigma(i)$, then $x_i$ appears in $E_j$ (nontrivially).

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
x_1+x_2 &= 0\\
x_1 - x_2 &= 0\\
x_3 &= 0\\
x_4 &= 0\\
x_5 &= 0\\
\vdots
\end{align}$$

this system has a unique trivial solution, and in each equation, at least one of $x_2, x_3,\dots$ shows up, since $x_2$ shows up in the first two, and then $x_i$ appears in the $i$-th equation.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the problem a bit to require there are not "so many" equations.

Comment: @Connor After your edit, my gut instinct is to say you cannot make such a system of equations, but I can't really prove it either way :(